# Use pandas to create dict out of CSV columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file(with single line) like this

```
drop1,drop2,key1,value1,key2,value2,key3,value3...keyN,valueN
```

The output I need is

```py
{
'key1':'value1',
'key2':'value2',
..
'keyN':'valueN',
}
```

I intend to use dataframes to do.
I tried using reshape and pivot, but being new to pandas, I am not able to figure it out.

Any pointer will be great help .

Comment: Every key has exactly one value?

Comment: Are they in order as you suggest in this example?

Comment: This single line is the data or it represents header?

Comment: @TobiasMolenaar Yes, each key has exactly one value and they are in order.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan It has no header, the single line represents data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `reshape` the values after first two columns to shape `(-1, 2)` where first column is `key` and second column is `value`

```py
df = pd.read_csv('your.csv', header=None)
out = (pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:, 2:].values.reshape(-1, 2))
       .set_index(0)[1].to_dict())
```

```
print(df)

       0      1     2       3     4       5     6       7     8       9
0  drop1  drop2  key1  value1  key2  value2  key3  value3  keyN  valueN

print(out)

{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3', 'keyN': 'valueN'}
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
df = pd.read_csv('your.csv', header=None)

lst = list(df)

# remove the strings with 'drop' in it
lst = [s for s in lst if 'drop' not in s]

# create key/value list based on lst
keys = [s for s in lst if 'key' in s]
value = [s for s in lst if 'val' in s]

# create dictionary using zip
d = dict(zip(keys, value))
```

Output:

```
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3', 'keyN': 'valueN'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method -

1. Read the csv without headers and pick only the first row
2. Filter this series based on "drop" value occurring (or any other condition)
3. Reshape it to key, value shaped array and convert to `dict`

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.read_csv("test.csv",header=None).iloc[0] #read csv without headers and pickup first row as a series

drop_idx = ~s.str.match("drop") #find values that contain "drop" or any other condition
arr = s[drop_idx].to_numpy().reshape(-1,2) #reshape the series into keys, values
output = dict(arr) #convert to dict
print(output)
```

```
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3', 'keyN': 'valueN'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If key and values are not ordered:

```
cols = df.iloc[0].to_list()

keys = sorted([val[-1] for val in cols if val.startswith('key')])
values = sorted([val[-1] for val in cols if val.startswith('val')])

my_dict = {f'key{key}': f'val{val}' for key, val in zip(keys, values)}
print(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without numpy and comprehensions:

```
s = pd.read_csv(r'c:\test\test111111.txt', header=None).iloc[0, 2:]  # get the Series without first two elements
print(s[1::2].set_axis(s[::2]).to_dict())  # get odd elements (values) and make index from even elements (keys)
```

Prints:

```
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
```